# composite control - How to get data from postbackdatacollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I know That composite control takes care of postback data automatically.
But I have a requirement where I am placing dropdown in a composite control and binding it on every postback.

After every postback, I see that dropdown is preserving its selected value.

The problem is, during a postback, when I try to get the selected value, Its empty.

I assume this is because I am trying to get selected value too early. (right after doing dropdown.databind())

Can somebody tell me, how to get the selected value from postback datacollection? OR
at what event will I get the correct selected value in a composite control ?

here my ovverriden databind method:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
    base.DataBind();

    addressDataSet = new AddressDataSet();
    countryAdapter = new CountriesForAddressTableAdapter();
    countryAdapter.Fill(addressDataSet.CountriesForAddress);

    maindropdown.DataSource = addressDataSet.CountriesForAddress;
    maindropdown.DataTextField = "Name";
    maindropdown.DataValueField = "CountryId";
    maindropdown.DataBind();



    if (!maindropdown.Value.IsNullOrEmpty()) <- THIS Value ALWAYS COMES AS NULL
    {
        fieldAdapter = new CountrySpecificFieldsTableAdapter();
        fieldAdapter.Fill(addressDataSet.CountrySpecificFields, int.Parse(maindropdown.Value));
    }
}
```

---

//HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[] <- I Found DROPDOWN'S VALUE IN HERE

but would like to know what would I have to do to get value via dropdowns property i.e. dropdown.selectedValue

Comment: From my experience you can only access constituent control once they are recreated in `CreateChildControls()`

Comment: I am ensuring that they are created by executing ensureChildControls();

the value is coming as null. not the dropdown

Comment: Did you make sure you are doing the binding of the dropdown in `if(!IsPostback)`?

Comment: No, Its binding every time in the onInit event of the control. But it preserves the value of dropdown.

Comment: I am sure at some event framework assign value from postback data to dropdown. I just dont know what that event is